# How to access an object from outside a threaded function

Tags: python

I have a python program that uses websockets:

```
def main():
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://foo.com/", on_message = on_ws_message)
    ws.on_open = on_ws_open
    ws.run_forever()

    anobject = AnObject.foo()

def on_ws_open(ws):
    ws.send('bar')

def on_ws_message(ws,message):
    print message
```

And I want to be able to call methods of `anobject` from the `on_ws_message()` function, which is automatically called and threaded. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use OOP:

```
class WhatEver(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://foo.com/", on_message = self.on_ws_message)
        self.ws.on_open = self.on_ws_open
        self.anobject = AnObject()

    def rin_forever(self):
        self.ws.run_forever()

    def on_ws_open(self, ws):
        self.anobject.foo()
        ws.send('bar')

    def on_ws_message(self, ws,message):
        print message

def main():
    ws=WhatEver()
    ws.run_forever()
```